# Mocking (moq) a GetAllAsync linq query with select

Tags: linq, unit-testing, automated-tests, moq

This is the specific line of code that I need to mock.

```
IGenericRepository<Foo> _fooRepository;
var listOfIds = await _fooRepository.GetAllAsync(o => o.Ids);
```

This is getting a list of int to represent the IDs in this data table. In other words,

```
select Ids from Table
```

FooRepository is implemented with IGenericRepository all using Entity Frameworks. The Ids field in the underlying table is just integer values and I'm trying to get a list of int out of it. I don't want any other columns.

So I have tried the following to no avail:

**1.**

```
_listOfIds = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};

_fooRepositoryMock.Setup(o => o.GetAllAsync(
It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>()))
.Returns((Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> Predicate) =>
Task.FromResult(_listOfids.Where(Predicate.Compile()).ToList() 
as ICollection<int>));
```

With this, IntelliSense complains that it cannot convert from...

```
'System.Func<Foo, Bool> to System.Func<int, int, bool>"
```

I tried at first messing around with the different types going in and out of the Func delegate. But I'm still stuck with the same error.

**2.**

I tried to then just use a default as I don't particularly mind if it tests this line completely. The list of IDs is just used later on in the method. But I need to mock it because if it's null, it's causing a test further down the test method to fail.

```
_listOfids= new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
_fooRepositoryMock.SetReturnsDefault(_listOfIds);
```

For some reason, when debugging the listOfIds remains null.

I'm kinda stuck on this one. The only thing that I can think of is to just stick this line of code into a helper method and mock the helper instead. But it just seems a really shoddy way to rewrite the code just to make a test pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the parameters for Returns method call. Also Moq includes another method for setting results of async methods.

```
_fooRepositoryMock.Setup(o => o.GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, int>>>()))
                  .ReturnsAsync(idList);
```

Comment: That was actually my initial attempt. The error this generates is "The type arguments for method "ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<Tmock, TResult>(IReturns,TMock, Task<Tresult>>, TResult) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Which is what led me down trying to compile the query in the first place

Comment: @JonSick Can you share the signature of GetAllAsync method?

Comment: Absolutely. Its '        Task<ICollection<TSelect>> GetAllAsync<TSelect>(Expression<Func<T, TSelect>> select);'

Comment: @JonSick What's the type of Ids property in Foo class?

Comment: All ID fields are int.

Comment: @JonSick Can you try it again? I updated the answer.

Comment: VS accepts it but for some reason when running through the debug tests, listOfIds in the real method remains null. EDIT: Fixed it. For some reason chaning it to a nullable int <Foo, int?> and changing the _listOfIds in the mock test method has made it work. Go figure! Thanks loads for the help! I've been stuck way too long on this one.